# Lower and Upper bounds for Ratio of Sum of two Sequences of positive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given two sequences of positive numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots a_k$ and  $b_1, b_2, \dots b_k$. Prove that
$$
\min_{i} \frac{a_i}{b_i} \leq \frac{\sum_{i}a_i}{\sum_{i}b_i} \leq \max_{i} \frac{a_i}{b_i}
$$

I have seen this inequality used in various proofs but I have no idea how to start proving such an inequality. Some hints would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set $M = \max_{i} a_i/b_i$. This means that for every $i$ $a_i/b_i \leq M$, so $a_i \leq Mb_i$. From this you get
$$
\sum_{i} a_i \leq \sum_{i} Mb_i = M \sum_{i} b_i,
$$
which is the same as
$$
\frac{\sum_{i} a_i}{\sum_{i} b_i} \leq M = \max_{i} \frac{a_i}{b_i}.
$$

For the other side you can do an analogous proof.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks Hugo!

Comment: Does this inequality have a name or can someone tell me a text in which it appears? I would like to be able to cite it by name or a reference in which it appears.

Comment: maybe check the book of concrete math, Summation Algebra